# Синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите разобрать предложение для того, чтобы составить схему предложения! "Загар-первый признак здоровья" Или все предложение- просто остальное уже поняли.(сложное предложение состоит из нескольких.) Предложение целиком: "Главное-нужно хорошо загореть. Загар-первый признак здоровья" -говорил Генка.

Comment: Анатолий Рыбаков, "Кортик"  
>Главное, нужно как следует загореть, –
озабоченно говорил Генка, натирая грудь и
плечи какой-то мазью. – Загар – первый
признак здоровья. А ну, Мишка, натри мне
спину, потом я тебе.
Миша взял у Генки баночку, понюхал,
брезгливо поморщился:
– Ну и дрянь! Фу!
– Много ты понимаешь! Это ореховое масло.
Первый сорт. А пахнет банка. Она из-под
гуталина.

Comment: Благодарю, но нужен разбор предложения в его сокращенном варианте)

Comment: Щас кто-нибудь придет

Comment: Сначала бы разобраться с предложениями, которыми Вы изъясняетесь.

Comment: А что не понятно? Это одно предложение из учебника русского языка- )) 
"Главное-нужно хорошо загореть. Загар-первый признак здоровья" -говорил Генка.

Comment: Ну еcли из учебника, тогда разберите по составу вот это:

*"Загар-первый признак здоровья" или все предложение- просто остальное уже поняли. предложение целиком: "главное-нужно хорошо загореть.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Главное-нужно хорошо загореть. Загар-первый признак здоровья", -говорил Генка.-повеств.,невоскл., простое с прямой речью. Схема:"П",-а.

К предложению с прямой речью составляется одна схема, показывающая расположение прямой речи и слов автора. Больше ничего не нужно.

Если есть дополнительное задание "подробный синтаксич. разбор и подробная схема, то добавляется:"Прямая речь состоит из двух  предложений:
1.Главное-нужно хорошо загореть.-повеств., невоскл.,прост.,двусост. полн.,неосложн.
2.Загар-первый признак здоровья.-повеств., невоскл.,прост.,двусост. полное,неосложн.

Comment: Да? Так просто? 5 класс- до этого в схемах писали подробно- подлежащее, сказуемое и др. члены предложения., открывали-закрывали квадратные скобки.... учились по "Перспективной школе России", теперь учимся по Бунееву- там столько нового для нашей системы)) Наверное из-за этого и теперь простых путей не искали...Большое спасибо!

Comment: Ничего сложного в Бунееве нет,нужно смотреть печатные рабочие тетради, там все примеры есть. Или классные тетради.

Comment: а вот учимся без них)) только по учебникам)) надеюсь, разберемся. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

На будущее: вот страничка, которая поможет в разборе http://uchim.org/russkij-yazyk/sintaksicheskij-razbor